# Same URL in multiple views in Django

Tags: django, url, view, handle

I'm developing a web application, and I need something like this:

```
url(r'^$', 'collection.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^$', 'collection.views.main', name='main'),
```

If the user is authenticated, go to main, otherwise go to home. On the home page, differently there will be a sign in a button. But these should be on the same URL pattern.

How can I handle it?

Comment: You can handle this redirect through a middleware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To handle that kind of thing you can use a single view that follows different code paths depending on the request state. That can mean something simple like setting a context variable to activate a sign in button, or something as complex and flexible as calling different functions - eg, you could write your home and main functions, then have a single dispatch view that calls them depending on the authentication state and returns the HTTPResponse object.

If authentication is all you need to check for, you don't even need to set a context variable - just use a `RequestContext` instance, such as the one you automatically get if you use the `render` shortcut. If you do that, `request` will be in the context so your template can check things like `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`.

Some examples:

```
def dispatch(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return main(request)
    else:
        return home(request)
```

Or for the simpler case:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        template = "main.html"
    else:
        template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template)
```

Answer (score 1):

While looking into a similar problem, I found an application - [django-multiurl](https://github.com/raiderrobert/django-multiurl). It has its limitations, but it is very convenient and useful.

Basically it allows you to raise a `ContinueResolving` exception in a view, which will result in next view being processed.

Answer (score 0):

For something reusable, you can create a parent view that holds multiple views and return the first one that returns without a specific error.

```
class ViewResolver(View):
    views = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       for view in self.views:
           try:
               return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           except DidNotResolve:
               continue


def view_resolver(*views):
    return ViewResolver.as_view(views=views)
```

Then in the urls:

```
...
url("home/", view_resolver(ClassView.as_view(), function_view)),
...
```

Notice this work with class-based views because the `as_view` method basically returns a function-based view.

Now, if you raise `DidNotResolve` in the `ClassView`, it will go to the `function_view`.