# Rendering different templates to the same URL pattern in Django

Tags: python, django

My question is similar to *[Same URL in multiple views in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289095/django-same-url-multiple-views)*, but I am not rendering templates on the basis of user_authentication, but rather on the basis of JavaScript enabled or disabled in the browser.

**What I am trying to do?**

I am trying to render the `index.html` page if JavaScript is enabled in the browser, otherwise I want to render `jsDisabled.html` page if it's disabled and both of the pages should be rendered on the same URL pattern, for example:

`localhost:8000` should either render `index.html` if JavaScript is enabled in the browser or it should render `jsDisabled.html` page if JavaScript is disabled.

*Note: I am checking if JavaScript is disabled in the browser by using the `<noscript>` tag which will run when JavaScript is disabled.*

Here is my code so far:

**base.html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body class="noJs">
        ...
        <a href="{% url 'index' 0 %}"> abc </a>
        ...
        <noscript>
            <style type="text/css">
                .noJs {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="{% ulr 'index' 1 %}"> /* This should render jsDisabled.html page on the same URL which is 'localhost:8000' */

        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  ...
  url(r'^(?P<flag>[0-1])$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request, flag):
    if (flag):
       return render(request, 'jsDisabled.html')
    else:
       return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: how do you know js is disabled? browsers don't announce this fact afaik.

Comment: `<noscript>` tag will tell. Look at my base.html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I finally found the solution :) And here it is:

#### base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="noJs">
    ...
    <a href="{% url 'index' 0 %}"> abc </a>
    ...
 </div>
 <noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .noJs {

            display: none;
       }
    </style>
    {% include 'includes/jsDisabled.html' %}
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
   url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls')),
   url(r'^temp/',views.temp, name="temp"),
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

#### views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def temp(request):
     return render(request,'temp.html')
```

I included the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/) built-in template tag as `{% include 'includes/jsDisabled.html' %}` suggested by [@noes1s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8778044/noes1s) by creating a folder named `includes` inside the templates folder and placing `jsDisabled.html` inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Django version you may need to specify TEMPLATE_DIR = in settings.py (in newer versions this isn't required).

Here is some helpful [information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include) on template and tag logic:

```
Main/templates/myapp/base.html
Main/templates/myapp/index.html
Main/templates/myapp/includes/yes_js.html
Main/templates/myapp/includes/no_js.html
```

#### base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

#### index.html:

```
{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<noscript>
{% include 'no_js.html' %}
</noscript>

{% include 'yes_js.html' %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: first of all thanks alot for the answer and secondly what is "Output <flag>" ? and i don't have to check for a condition here because <noscript> means js is disabled in which case i simply have to include a jsDisabled.html page here.

Comment: That was pseudo-code assuming your test logic. I don't think you want to include both no_js and yes_js simultaneously, You will still have to run your test case but this allows you to run the logic on the front end and only include the html needed.

Comment: Updated solution. If no test case just include the no_js.html between <noscript>. The yes_js will still render though so I recommend some test case.

Comment: `{% include 'jsDisabled.html' %}` throws an error and i saw it on the docs but i didn't get it. and i want to render jsDisabled.html in my base.html because my base.html includes the code for displaying header & footer of the page which needs javascript if i try to display jsDisabled.html in index.html it would display header and footer as well which i don't want.

Comment: {% include 'file.html' %}  pulls from main/templates/myapp/includes/file.html  check and make sure the directory path is accurate.   I like to have a the base.html for standard header and footer and script info globally. Use an index.html that {% extends 'myapp/base.html' %} then create includes content to populate these templates.

Comment: Sorry my bad `{% include 'jsDisabled.html' %}` displays a blank page and  `{% include '/static/templates/jsDisabled.html' %}` throw error `TemplateDoesNotExist` which i checked in docs but didn't get it. I have put all my templates in a static folder

Comment: Please refer to the top of my answer. You need to create an includes directory  static/templates/includes  and drop that jsDisabled.html in that directory. Then {% include 'jsDisabled.html' %}  should render that file

Comment: did that too but it still throws `TemplateDoesNotExist`

Comment: Can you post the debug info? Also update your question with the new code pertaining to these .html files.

Comment: I changed my path to this `/static/templates/appname/includes/jsDisabled.html` and now it doesn't display any exception rather it displays nothing. 

Comment: Try [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files) link. It will cover your original attempt to [render pages with data from views.py](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files#toc-rendering-templates-with-data-from-views) and will also cover [including code snippets into templates](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files#toc-including-snippets-into-your-templates)  Be sure to review the beginning because it lays out setting up settings, urls, static files and directories.

Comment: My attempt is to "Render pages from views.py based on the value passed by a base.html template" not "Render pages with data/variable from views.py" that is the opposite i guess. And i just followed the link you send but that still displays nothing when js is disabled in a browser. And doesn't my question deserve a vote ??

Comment: I just included this `{% include 'partials/jsDisabled.html' %} ` in my index.html and just what it works :) but when i include the same in base.html under <noscript> tag and disable the javaScript in my browser it displays nothing why ? :(

Comment: the problem was with this `<body class="noJs">` it was not letting `{% include 'includes/jsDisabled.html' %}` to be rendered so i just created a div element inside a body and placed the noJs class in it just as mentioned in my answer. Btw without you i could not have accomplished this thanks a ton sir, or mam whatever you are ;)